# Using Javascript to detect keypress event in text editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I want to bind a javascript function to trigger whenever a user presses a key in the text editor. However it seems that the text editor is an iframe and this is easier said than done. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Which editor precisely do you want to target? "Main" content when editing the post? What had you tried so far?